# welcome.blade.php not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In a fresh laravel project, I am creating an authentication system using

> php artisan make:auth

Then, I rename the following file:

> welcome.blade.php **to**  welcome1.blade.php

and replace that one with a new file carrying the same name:

> welcome.blade.php

Then I refresh the page, but it still shows the old page view in the browser. Even after I have changed the text in welcome1.blade.php, the view hasn't changed. How do I change the blade pages created during the 'make:auth' command?

Comment: Are you loading the view through a controller or directly through the route file? You also need to update the line of code in either the controller or route file that *calls the view*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WelcomeController you need to change the call to the view. If not, you need to change your route file to match.

```
public function index() {
  return view('welcome1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your application cache by running php artisan cache:clear in your terminal.

Comment: actually, you should see waterloomatt's answer. You also need to change the view you're returning from your controller like he suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the view from Routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Make sure that the view you loading is actually called `welcome.blade.php` or if you want to load welcome `welcome1.blade.php`
If you are running this through Controllers

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Then Controller :

```
    //to return welcome
    public function index(){
    return view('welcome');
}
    //to return welcome1
    public function index(){
    return view('welcome1');
}
```